# NodeJs development offline in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, offline

I'm trying to implement a developer workflow with docker, with the ability to develop offline (as in, not having to run `npm install` when you switch between branches that have differing dependencies)

The most intuitive way to do that is to store dependencies in source control. This has its own issues especially when using modules that compile dependencies. I have tried nearly everything I could think of and find:

- `npm pack`ing my projects dependencies, storing in source but this doesn't store my dependencies' dependencies
- storing node_modules in source, copying this to the container and running `npm rebuild` but it [doesn't actually trigger a rebuild](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17536)
- running `npm install --no-registry` so t triggers a rebuild but doesn't try to call out, but it actually calls out to the public registry anyway
- other solutions I've seen like [Node-PAC](https://github.com/mikefrey/node-pac) seem abandoned
- npmbox looks the most promising but it requires that it's installed on the target globally, which would work in a container I can build but not production, unless we start deploying containers in production.

Is this a fruitless effort? Lack of network access is rare and would only really be needed when installing a new module or moving between revisions that have differing dependencies

Comment: While I don't relate to the need (and I use Canonical's Juju Local container implementation to run containers for local dev), here's an idea: since node_modules is a temp gitignored folder, why not create an aggregate of all the dependencies of any branch and store them in say, devDependencies of the package.json file for the project. This way, all node_modules are available for any branch being switched to. *Caveat: this won't work if you have side-by-side versions of NPM modules across branches*

Comment: That's part of the issue I foresee in the future: a likely scenario in this hypothetical situation is that a dependency's version would change between close revisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to setup a private npm repository and to configure it to cache public repository. There are several options to implement this, I would recommend to try Nexus: https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss

Comment: Yeah, I already have this available to me, but the proposed scenario is "what if I get on a plane and want to switch between branches?) although I'm really starting to feel like it's such a corner case it's not worth pursuing

Comment: I'm sorry for not being precise enough, but I suggest you to setup a private repo on your laptop. :) This way you will have all required deps with you everywhere.

Comment: after some thought, I think you're right, this is probably the only way to do it in a way that doesn't require storing binary blobs in source, or tweaking npm significantly. I did find this module called local-npm that seems to do the job and also starts up faster than sonatype

Comment: I can also recommend you to try https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio, a sinopia fork (sinopia is not maintained anymore). I never tried it, but do have a very positive experience with sinopia.